# Accessing Java from Ruby via RPC

Tags: java, ruby, rpc

I have a Java API in a server which I need to access from a Ruby program. What are quick/easy ways to setup a system that can connect the Java server to Ruby via RPC? Assume the API exposed via RPC is simple and RPC parameters are simple data types and negligible in size, so they have minimal serialization/deserialization overhead. Only requirement is that if something bad happens in the server, then it should be reported as an RPC exception to Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

I use local Bayeux connection to do interop messaging, the nice thing is there is a client/server for almost any language.